# How to Read a string From a File Wix

Tags: wix, installation

There is a file test.txt which is having a text "FileName"

I want to read this string "FileName" from the file test.txt in wix and somehow I want to assign this string to a directory name.

I want the below mentioned to happen, reading from a file.

< Directory Id="testing" Name=FileName >

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks in Advance,
Pradeep Kumar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a custom action that reads the text file content and places it into a property. Then you can try to reference that property in the directory name, don't know if WiX supports this, but other setup authoring tools do so chances are WiX does too.

**VERY IMPORTANT**. You must schedule the custom action to be executed as **immediate** and **before** the [file costing standard actions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368593%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).