# Sharing properties: "error LGHT0094 : Unresolved reference to symbol"

Tags: wix

I'm trying to share a property between several products, which is not set by default. Except for one product, where I want to set it to a value.

So in shared.wxi:

```
<Include>
    <Property Id="MYPROP" Secure="yes"></Property>
</Include>
```

And in product.wxs:

```
<Wix>
    <Product>
        <?include ..\shared\shared.wxi?>
        <SetProperty Id="MYPROP" Value="1" After="InstallInitialize"/>
    </Product>
</Wix>
```

But our build system complains about:

```
error LGHT0094 : Unresolved reference to symbol 'WixAction:InstallUISequence/InstallInitialize' in section 'Product:{583365A4-93C2-434A-BCD8-8A1035DF2AC7}'
```

I'm not even sure if `After="InstallInitialize"` (or Before=...) is the right place, I just want to set the property for this product right after the include but before anything else is considered. Also, I'm pretty much clueless about the whole WIX system, I'm just trying to fix something quickly while the knowledgable colleague is on vacation.

UPDATE - Now I tried this instead of `SetProperty`, but still get the same error:

```
  <CustomAction Id="CA_SETMYPROP" Property="MYPROP" Value="1" />
  <InstallUISequence>
    <Custom Action="CA_SETMYPROP" Before="InstallInitialize" />
  </InstallUISequence>
```

UPDATE 2 - Now I replaced `InstallUISequence` with `InstallExecuteSequence` and it does what I want. See Rob Mensching's answer for an explanation and an alternative solution.

```
  <CustomAction Id="CA_SETMYPROP" Property="MYPROP" Value="1" />
  <InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="CA_SETMYPROP" Before="InstallInitialize" />
  </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: [Maybe have a quick look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51007189/how-to-read-content-of-text-file-in-wix-toolset-bootstrapper/51010105#51010105).

Comment: Can you quickly explain what you need to achieve? MSI tends to fight back when you try to make quick fixes.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul Yes, I was aware of those variables. I guess I could have transformed the shared properties into variables to solve my problem but that would have forced me to change many places where those properties are already used.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This issue threw *me* for a loop when I first encountered it (fairly recently). The error message is correct but could be much more helpful<sup>*</sup>.

The root issue is that `InstallInitialize` does not exist in the `InstallUISequence`. By default, `SetProperty` uses `both` for the `Sequence` attribute. That means the set property is scheduled before/after `InstallInitialize` action in both the `InstallExecuteSequence` and the `InstallUISequence`. Since `InstallInitialize` does not exist in `InstallUISequence` you'll get the error:

```
Unresolved reference to symbol 'WixAction:InstallUISequence/InstallInitialize'
```

The fix is to use `Sequence='execute'` to only schedule the setting of the property in the `InstallExecuteSequence` where `InstallInitialize` lives. Alternatively, you can pick a different action to schedule before/after.

Using `SetProperty` would go a lot like this:

```
<SetProperty Id="MYPROP" Value="1" After="InstallInitialize" Sequence="execute" />
```

<sup>*</sup> Improving the error message is on my radar.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out in the meantime that InstallInitialize simply does not exist in InstallUISequence, see my second update. Not sure about your Sequence='execute' part, where does that go? The Custom node has a Sequence attribute, but that's an integer. The CustomAction node has an Execute attribute, is that what you meant?

Comment: Nevermind, got it. Your solution using the Sequence attribute in the SetProperty node is shorter and less redundant. Care to add an example line for illustration? I had to read your answer thrice to fully understand it.